# How to make .coffee file working on a check box in a form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. First, should I run "bundle exec rake:precompile" every time after I modify a .coffee file? I found it usually doesn't take effect automatically.
2. I have a form, I want checking the checkbox to show something on the web page.

I wrote a file in `app\assets\javascripts\testbeds.js.coffee`, with the content:

```
alert "ddd"

$(".checkbox1").click ->
  alert "aaa"

$("#manually").click ->
  alert "aaa"

$("#manually").change ->
  alert "aaa"

$('input[type=checkbox]').on 'change', ->
  alert(0)
```

And a view file: `app\views\testbeds\edit.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Editing testbed</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Show', @testbed %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', testbeds_path %>
```

The content of `app\views\testbeds\_form.html.erb` is only one checkbox:

```
<%= form_for(@testbed) do |f| %>
  <% if @testbed.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@testbed.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this testbed from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @testbed.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :configuration_id %><br />
    <% selected = (@configuration.nil?) ? nil : @configuration.id %>
    <%= f.select :configuration_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@configurations, 'id', 'name', selected) %>
    <label class="checkbox1">
     <input id="manually" type="checkbox" name="manually" value="manually">
    </label>

      <label id="label"> Choose resources manually</label>
  </div>
  <div id="resources">
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I click or check the checkbox, the `alert`s don't work. But first line's `alert` "ddd" shows correctly.

The compiled content in application.js is like below. I am not sure if the "( jQuery );" belong to previous function or this function, just attach it.

```
  }

})( jQuery );
(function() {

  alert("ddd");

  $(".checkbox1").click(function() {
    return alert("aaa");
  });

  $("#manually").click(function() {
    return alert("aaa");
  });

  $("#manually").change(function() {
    return alert("aaa");
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    return alert(0);
  });

}).call(this);
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
```

Could somebody tell me the reason and teach me how this works?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you don't need to manually recompile coffeescript files in the rails development environment, generally
2. Make sure you've read the [asset pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).    This could be caused by app/assets/application.js needing to require the testbeds javascript file.
3. Change your code just to do an alert('test') to verify your javascript is being loaded in the asset pipeline properly - if that works, it's just a problem with the way you are doing the jquery binding

EDIT:
What is likely going wrong is that once you run rake assets:precompile locally, it will serve assets exclusively out of public/assets.  You need to delete that directory if you want to return to compile-on-demand behavior (which is what you want)

Comment: 1: You don't need to manually recompile coffeescript files **in development environment** but you have to run `rails assets:precompile` for the production env.

Comment: @MrYoshiji  I know but lalameat post implied this was in a development environment - perhaps lalameat meant production, but I doubt it.

Comment: @MrYoshiji updated my post to make it clear I was referring to the dev environment

Comment: Yes, it is development environment, I always check it in app/assets/application.js. I thought the precompile should only take effect to production environment(also need some change to in  config.assets.precompile to include the file). But maybe sometimes I saw the modification didn't take effect automatically in development       env. I am not sure. Then do I need to restart the rais server every time after the modification?

Comment: And, some change like step 3 I did in the first, it worked. Just alert no matter what. I think it is loaded. But change to the code I posted, didn't work.

Comment: I confirmed the one line test code " alert "aaa" " can take effect, but only after I rake:precompile and then started my "development" environment. I don't know why. But the little real code about the checkbox always didn't work.

Comment: @lalameat see my latest update, you need to delete the precompile directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on('change')`. Here is a jsfiddle in normal jQuery (non Coffee): http://jsfiddle.net/CrQP6/

In Coffee, it would be

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on 'change', ->
  alert(0)
```